# RequiredFieldValidator Issue

Tags: c#, .net, requiredfieldvalidator

My requiredfield control is validating the "SEL"(default invalid value) value but when I do change the value to a valid one, the ErrorMessage/Text does not disappear until I submit the form again.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDocumentType" runat="server" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Code" />
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="ddlDocumentType" Text="*" ID="rfvDocumentType" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="SEL" />
```

It happens in all my dropdownlists/requiredfieldvalidators. How does the Text/ErrorMessage disappear when I change the value on the dropdownlist ? I'm guessing it has to disappear when the option is valid !

Thanks,

Comment: What are display="dynamic" and Initialvalue="SEL" there for?  When I don't use those, I get the desired behavior that you are describing when I use RequiredFieldValidator.

Comment: display="Dynamic" is to show the message near the control to be validated and the InitialValue="SEL" is to tell that the value "SEL" on the dropdownlist is not valid, could be ""

Answer (score 0):

A similar question is discussed [here](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/166_Restrict_AspNet_Validator_controls_to_Fire_on_Page_Submit.aspx). I think the problem is the way validation javascript works. Just to try, you can also add EnableClientScript=true attribute.

Comment: EnableClientScript="true" is the default setting isn't it?